# Convert Enum to string in SubMethod

Tags: c#, methods, enums

I am struggling with the correct cast.
May someone can show me the right direction?

See my example below:

```
public enum E_Enum1
{
Value1,
Value2,
Value3
}

public enum E_Enum2
{
Bla,
blubb,
whatever
}

public void myMethod(Enum e)
{
//print e.value in int
//print e.toString()
}


myMethod(E_Enum2.whatever);
myMethod(E_Enum1.Value2);
```

I want to get a result of:

```
2
whatever
1
Value2
```

Comment: Ok, i think i had a other issue. it seems  to work now with Convert.toInt(e) and e.toString() dont know

Comment: If you pass enum value as `Enum`, CLR will [box the value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/boxing-and-unboxing). Use generic type to avoid boxing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*EDIT: Changed answer to avoid using string interpolation and `string.Format` that box the enum value*

Use generic type:

```
public void myMethod<TEnum>(TEnum e) where TEnum : Enum
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.ToString("D"));
    Console.WriteLine(e.ToString("G"));
}
```

Then call method:

```
myMethod(E_Enum2.whatever);
myMethod(E_Enum1.Value2);
```

Comment: Just for reference: [Enumeration format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/enumeration-format-strings) (feel free to use in answer)

Comment: Alternative: `Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToInt32(e)); Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());`

Comment: `Convert.ToInt32(e)` will box the enum value, but it does remind me, because the type is constrained, we should just use `.ToString()`.